# How to pass output from select to outside of select at global scope?

Tags: select, go

I cannot pass string variable outside of a `select` statement.

Case (simplified):

I have a synchronous script which uses `select` with two options

1. `timeout` (3 seconds)
2. `default` which is using channel to change value of a string.

When we check result of a string inside the `select` - it shows correctly.

But once we leave the `select` statement, variable is reverted to the value it was before.

```
package main

import (
    "log"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    timeout := time.After(3 * time.Second)
    pollInt := time.Second

    var ret string = "EMPTY"

OuterLoop:
    for {
        select {
        case <-timeout:
            log.Printf("[select][timeout] select timeout, break select and for loops")
            break OuterLoop

        default:
            log.Printf("[select][default] Processing our actions")

            ch := make(chan string, 1)

            go func(ch chan string) {
                var res string = "NOT EMPTY"
                ch <- res
            }(ch)

            select {
            case ret := <-ch:
                log.Printf("channel has a result")
                log.Printf("showing content of string AT THE SELECT: %v", ret)
            case <-time.After(1 * time.Second):
                log.Printf("timeout")

            }

        }
        log.Printf("[for] Sleep for a second..")
        time.Sleep(pollInt)
    }

    log.Printf("Starting to do some important actions.. (regardless was previous actions success or timeout)")
    /* ... */

    log.Printf("showing content of string: %v", ret)

    if ret == "NOT EMPTY" {
        log.Printf("SCRIPT FINISHED CORRECTLY")
    } else {
        log.Printf("SCRIPT FAILED")
    }

}
```

Result of script run:

```
2009/11/10 23:00:00 [select][default] Processing our actions
2009/11/10 23:00:00 channel has a result
2009/11/10 23:00:00 showing content of string AT THE SELECT: NOT EMPTY
2009/11/10 23:00:00 [for] Sleep for a second..
2009/11/10 23:00:01 [select][default] Processing our actions
2009/11/10 23:00:01 channel has a result
2009/11/10 23:00:01 showing content of string AT THE SELECT: NOT EMPTY
2009/11/10 23:00:01 [for] Sleep for a second..
2009/11/10 23:00:02 [select][default] Processing our actions
2009/11/10 23:00:02 channel has a result
2009/11/10 23:00:02 showing content of string AT THE SELECT: NOT EMPTY
2009/11/10 23:00:02 [for] Sleep for a second..
2009/11/10 23:00:03 [select][timeout] select timeout, break select and for loops
2009/11/10 23:00:03 Starting to do some important actions.. (regardless was previous actions success or timeout)
2009/11/10 23:00:03 showing content of string: EMPTY
2009/11/10 23:00:03 SCRIPT FAILED
```

But I'd expect:

```
2009/11/10 23:00:00 [select][default] Processing our actions
2009/11/10 23:00:00 channel has a result
2009/11/10 23:00:00 showing content of string AT THE SELECT: NOT EMPTY
2009/11/10 23:00:00 [for] Sleep for a second..
2009/11/10 23:00:01 [select][default] Processing our actions
2009/11/10 23:00:01 channel has a result
2009/11/10 23:00:01 showing content of string AT THE SELECT: NOT EMPTY
2009/11/10 23:00:01 [for] Sleep for a second..
2009/11/10 23:00:02 [select][default] Processing our actions
2009/11/10 23:00:02 channel has a result
2009/11/10 23:00:02 showing content of string AT THE SELECT: NOT EMPTY
2009/11/10 23:00:02 [for] Sleep for a second..
2009/11/10 23:00:03 [select][timeout] select timeout, break select and for loops
2009/11/10 23:00:03 Starting to do some important actions.. (regardless was previous actions success or timeout)
2009/11/10 23:00:03 showing content of string: NOT EMPTY
2009/11/10 23:00:03 SCRIPT FINISHED CORRECTLY
```

Playground: https://play.golang.org/p/uPKZtQQkm7p

Any ideas?

Comment: You're shadowing `ret`. Use `case ret = <-ch` instead.

Comment: Relevant: https://golang.org/cmd/vet/#hdr-Shadowed_variables

Comment: don't reassgin `ret`. use `case ret = <-ch:` instead of `case ret := <-ch:`

Comment: Why people are downvoting a valid question? Bad mood? Feeling of elitism?